# setting up oidc authentication with gitlab runner to deploy docker images to ECR

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, amazon-ecr

Below is the `gitlab ci` script which builds the docker image and pushed the docker image to Dockerhub. This script is working fine.

```
image: docker:latest
stages:
  - build
  - deploy
services:
  - docker:dind
before_script:
  - echo -n $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD | docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER --password-stdin $CI_REGISTRY
Build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest || true
    - >
      docker build
      --pull
      --cache-from $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
      --label "org.opencontainers.image.title=$CI_PROJECT_TITLE"
      --label "org.opencontainers.image.url=$CI_PROJECT_URL"
      --label "org.opencontainers.image.created=$CI_JOB_STARTED_AT"
      --label "org.opencontainers.image.revision=$CI_COMMIT_SHA"
      --label "org.opencontainers.image.version=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
      --tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
      .
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
Deploy:
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
    - docker tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
```

I need to push the image to `ECR` and the below script is working correctly for authenticating.

```
image: 
  name: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-base:latest
  entrypoint: 
    - '/usr/bin/env'

assume role:
    script:
        - >
          STS=($(aws sts assume-role-with-web-identity
          --role-arn arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/gitlab-aws-access-role
          --role-session-name "GitLabRunner-${CI_PROJECT_ID}-${CI_PIPELINE_ID}"
          --web-identity-token $CI_JOB_JWT_V2
          --duration-seconds 3600
          --query 'Credentials.[AccessKeyId,SecretAccessKey,SessionToken]'
          --output text))
        - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="${STS[0]}"
        - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="${STS[1]}"
        - export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="${STS[2]}"
        - TOKEN=$(base64 <<< $CI_JOB_JWT_V2)
        - echo $TOKEN
        - echo ${AWS_SESSION_TOKEN}
        - aws sts get-caller-identity
        - aws s3 ls
```

My qeustion is to use the above script and integrate with the first script so that the gitlab ci will authenticate and push the docker images to the `ECR`.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add the steps for logging into ECR, which are shown in the AWS console when you click "view push commands" on your image repository and [described in the documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/docker-push-ecr-image.html).

```yaml
variables: # set these values per your AWS account/region
  REGION: "<AWS REGION>"
  ECR_REGISTRY: "<AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com"
script:
  # ... set AWS credentials as you already have
  - aws ecr get-login-password --region $REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $ECR_REGISTRY
  - docker build -t "$ECR_REGISTRY/my-image:latest" .
  - docker push "$ECR_REGISTRY/my-image:latest"
```

Comment: But we need the aws-cli to run the `aws ecr` commands for which we need the image `registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-base`. How do we mention both the images?

Comment: @zilcuanu you would have a few options... one would be to use `image: docker` and install aws-cli as a job step. You could also use the gitlab aws-base image and install docker in that as part of the job. Alternatively still, you could build your own image containing both docker and aws-cli.